# "Runtime error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" from Script task

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I have a SSIS package with a script task, I get the following error when i try to run it in my local system. It works fine for my collegues as well as in production. However, I am not able to run it locally, to test. I keep a debug point in the main method, but it is never reached, I get the error before it goes to main method.

[image]

I am using VS 2010, .Net framework 4.5.

The script task does compile. I get the following messages SSIS package "..\Test.dtsx" starting. Error: 0x1 at Test: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Task failed: Test SSIS package "..\Test.dtsx" finished: Success. The program '[2552] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The following is the code:

```
public void Main()
{
try
{
 LogMessages("Update Bug package execution started at :: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
 LogMessages("Loading package configuration values to local variables.");

strDBConn = Dts.Variables["User::DBConnection"] != null ? Dts.Variables["User::DBConnection"].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
strTPCUrl = Dts.Variables["User::TPCUrl"] != null ? Dts.Variables["User::TPCUrl"].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;

TfsTeamProjectCollection objTPC = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(strTPCUrl));
WorkItemStore objWIS = new WorkItemStore(objTPC);
WorkItemCollection objWIC = objWIS.Query("SELECT...");

foreach (WorkItem wi in objWIC)
{
}

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

When I commented the code from TfsTeamProjectCollection objTPC = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(strTPCUrl)); The script executes successfully. However, if i keep TfsTeamProjectCollection objTPC = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(strTPCUrl)); and comment the rest, i get the exception.
I do have access to the URL.

I am using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll, in my script task. However the dll version in the package is 10.0, and the version of the dll in my GAC is 12.0. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: We too are perplexed. Perhaps its due to a lack of code in the question. Otherwise, there's no way we can provide an authoritative answer. It's *likely* a custom DLL/3rd party software installed on those machines that's not on yours but that's just speculation

Comment: Wow, that doesn't give you much to go on, does it?  Have you combed through all the messages getting written out to the DEBUG window when you run it (in debug mode) in SSDT?  That would be your best bet for finding clues as to what the exception thrown by the invocation target actually was.

Comment: Also, can you verify that the script task will compile on your machine?

Comment: The script task does compile. I get the following messages SSIS package "..\Test.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0x1 at Test: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Task failed: Test
SSIS package "..\Test.dtsx" finished: Success.
The program '[2552] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: I wanted to figure out what i need to check, as code is fine since it works for others. The debugger doesnt get into the main method, so not sure what code i need to provide

Comment: It doesnt show any errors, it compiles successfully

Comment: Either you need to post the code or go through your references and see if something in there isn't "normal"

Comment: I am using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll, in my script task. However the dll version in the package is 10.0, and the version of the dll in my GAC is 12.0. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: If its a script task, you can create a simple console application out of it in visual studio , try that and see the error for yourself at which point you are receiving this. I believe above exception is raised when you try to invoke something you cant.

Comment: I have added the code, if i have this line TfsTeamProjectCollection objTPC = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(strTPCUrl)); I am getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem (i.e. the same error code Error: 0x1 ...).

The issue was with some of the libraries referenced from a missing folder.

Removing the references and adding them back from the correct path fixed the issue.

The Microsoft Reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164.aspx) related to the Error code is very generic and doesn't help you much. 
However, reading other articles it is quite likely it  indicates an unknown failure reason to run the Script Task.

- Hexadecimal code: 0x1
- Decimal Code: 1
- Symbolic Name: DTS_MSG_CATEGORY_SERVICE_CONTROL
- Description: Incorrect function.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error message when I referred to a passed ssis variable in Dts.Variables["User::xxxx].Value(); where xxxx did not exist and was not passed from the calling program.  It was a simple Console.Writeline referring to a passed variable that didn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this error by changing the **TargetServerVersion** of the **SSIS Project**.

[Integration Services Project Property Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9MF6.png)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was **missing DLLs** or not having the correct version installed on the server.

Locally all tests were fine but on the server the error message `Runtime error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation` kept popping up.

No exception handler would be able to catch that error - the code in the script task would not even be executed, as soon as a DLL would be needed, that is not in the assembly cache on the server (it could happen on a local machine as well, with the same error).

The difficulty here is finding out what is missing and then either update the references to the correct version or install the missing DLL in the assembly cache with `gacutil`. The way I approached the debugging was to remove parts of the code in the script task until that error wouldn't appear, then analyze the missing part for references.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a different situation and not intended to be the end all be all solution for everyone.

When I was installing my DLLs into the GAC I forgot to run my script as Administrator and the script ran silently without error as though it was working.

I felt really dumb when I realized that's what I did wrong. Hopefully this can help prevent other people from wasting time on something so silly.

For reference this is what I use for installing my DLLs into the GAC and I modified it to tell me when I am not running it as Administrator now:

```
#https://superuser.com/questions/749243/detect-if-powershell-is-running-as-administrator
$isAdmin = ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] `
  [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() `
).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)

if($isAdmin -eq $false)
{
    Write-Host "You have to run this script as Administrator or it just won't work!" -ForegroundColor Red

    return;
}

$strDllPath = "C:\PathToYourDllsHere\"

#Note that you should be running PowerShell as an Administrator
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")            
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish            


$arr = @(
    "YourDLL01.dll",
    "YourDLL02.dll",
    "YourDLL03.dll"
)

get-date

foreach($d in $arr)
{
    $p = ($strDllPath + $d);

    $p

    $publish.GacInstall($p);
}

#If installing into the GAC on a server hosting web applications in IIS, you need to restart IIS for the applications to pick up the change.
#Uncomment the next line if necessary...
#iisreset
```

Credit for how to determine if your PowerShell script is running in Admin mode or not:
https://superuser.com/questions/749243/detect-if-powershell-is-running-as-administrator

Answer (score 1):

After not having any luck with the other answers here, I finally found that in my package, the problem was that I had created a new variable but not carried its name across into my new copy of the C# script. The variables were the ones to be used as connection string expressions. So it was ultimately a matter of changing:

```
Dts.Variables["Exists"].Value = File.Exists(Dts.Variables["OldSSISPackageVariableName"].Value.ToString());
```

to:

```
Dts.Variables["Exists"].Value = File.Exists(Dts.Variables["NewSSISPackageVariableName"].Value.ToString());
```

Once I kept them in sync, it worked fine.

Comment: No idea why Visual Studio can't bring itself to handle this scenario more gracefully. Hidden characters in the error message? Are you serious? And it's still identical 7 years later.

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed, when added reference to dll version 12.0.0 and changed Target Framework to .Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I, in the script task, tried to fetch data like this:

```cs
public void Main()
{
    using (var connection = Dts.Connections["localhost.Test"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection)
    {
        connection.Open();

        var command = new SqlCommand("select * from Table;", connection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{reader[0]} {reader[1]} {reader[2]}");
        }
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

However, my connection is of the type OLE DB, and therefore I needed to connect to it like this instead:

```cs
public void Main()
{
    var connectionString = Dts.Connections["localhost.Test"].ConnectionString;
    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var command = new OleDbCommand("select * Table;", connection);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{reader[0]} {reader[1]} {reader[2]}");
        }
    }

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Notice that I'm using `OleDbConnection` here.

Answer (score 0):

For me what fixed the issue was updating the string parameter I passed to the script. it was missing "" at the end of the path (i.e. "e:\arcive" - needed to add "" at the end)