# Runtime error in script task

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis, script-task

We have a fully running database server, say **serverA**, whose data are refreshed daily.
We want to **duplicate this database on a different server**, says **serverB**, so that we have a test environment. The databases has been restored to serverB.

Like serverA, we want serverB's data to be refreshed daily also, so the tests we conduct on serverB can be said as fully accurate since they will have the same data as serverA. We **deployed the SSIS packages used in serverA in serverB and copied the SQL Server Agent Jobs in serverB** also.

I am trying to modify these jobs and packages so that they can run smoothly on serverB, I'm changing directory paths, server names, etc.

Now, there is this job that always fails because of a package, zip.dtsx.
**zip.dtsx** retrieves files from directoryA, compresses them and saves the compressed file to directoryB, then deletes the file in directoryA. However, I cannot figure out why it's having a **runtime error**.

zip.dtsx has a script task named **Zip files**.

The script language is **Microsoft Visual C# 2010**

The **ReadOnlyVariables** set are `User::DestinationPath, User::NamePart, User::SourcePath,$Package::filename`

The script is,

```
public void Main()
        {
            String sourcePath = Convert.ToString(Dts.Variables["SourcePath"].Value);
            String namePart = Convert.ToString(Dts.Variables["NamePart"].Value);
            String destinationPath = Convert.ToString(Dts.Variables["DestinationPath"].Value);
            FileStream sourceFile = File.OpenRead(@sourcePath + namePart);
            FileStream destFile = File.Create(@destinationPath + namePart);

            GZipStream compStream = new GZipStream(destFile, CompressionMode.Compress);

            try
            {
                int theByte = sourceFile.ReadByte();
                while (theByte != -1)
                {
                    compStream.WriteByte((byte)theByte);
                    theByte = sourceFile.ReadByte();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                compStream.Dispose();
                sourceFile.Close();
                destFile.Close();
                File.Delete(@sourcePath + namePart);
            } 

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

The error I'm getting, when I execute the task in Microsoft Visual Studio -> Right click Script Task object -> Execute task
[image]

I am not familiar with Microsoft Visual C# and I have just also begun using SSIS packages, so I'm really at a loss.

**UPDATE**:
I tried commenting out different lines in the C# script. Finally, when I commented out `File.Delete(@sourcePath + namePart);`, the job calling zip.dtsx has succeeded. However, I am not sure why I'm having an error with this line. I'm not sure if it is because of permissions or any other else.

Comment: Can you check script task invocation itself is failing or it is failing to invocation of GZipStream?

Comment: Did you added "using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression"?

Comment: Hi @Kannan Kandasamy, yes there is at teh top of the script.
`#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
#endregion`

Comment: How can I check if it is in invocation of GZipStream it is failing?

Comment: You can try commenting GZip code and check whether the plain script task is running fine?

Comment: I commented GZipStream and I'm still encountering the runtime error. Also, I've seen this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997381/runtime-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-from-sc). I already removed and re-added the references but stil same runtime error occurs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125686/discussion-between-kannan-kandasamy-and-krish).

Comment: This has been answered in my other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081471/ssis-package-fails-on-file-delete-of-script-task).