# Run SSIS Package after checking entries in database table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl, ssis-2012

### Background

I would like to load data for 8 tables from Source *(This gets data from some other place)* to Target. I have a control table in my source that maintains entries every time a table is loaded. So before I start my SSIS package, I need to check if the control table in source has entries for all 8 tables.

### SSIS Package Structure

1. Two variables `RecordCount` (default 0) & `SQLQueryForRecordCount` (SQL Query to get record count from control table)
2. Execute SQL Task - Here I am executing the select query to get record count and passing the result to variable `RecordCount`
3. While connecting data flow with `execute sql script`, I have selected `Expression as Evaluation Operation` and expression as `@[User::RecordCount] == 8` so that Data Flow will be executed when the `RecordCount = 8`.

Everything works fine till now.

The Problem is we are not sure about when the entries will be inserted into control table in source (it can be done anytime in a 3 hours window). So I would like to loop the 2nd step (execute sql script) until the `RecordCount` variable value reaches 8 and then kick off next data flow tasks.

How to achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: If there is a 3 hours window time, why you don't set the package execution time to execute at the end of the 3 hours?

Comment: @TheEsisia Generally this situation comes up when there is a window to *begin* processing, but you still want to start as soon as possible...

Comment: Yes Aaron, you are right. Even though there is 3 hour window, we would like to start data load into next system as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to do this within a stored procedure, and also prefer the ability to adjust it without editing/deploying/promoting my packages.

In SSIS, you will want a simple execute SQL task that calls the stored procedure. 
 Then for the stored procedure, you would want something like:

```
DECLARE @CountProcessed int

SELECT @CountProcessed = SUM(ControlField)
FROM ControlTable

WHILE @CountProcessed <> 8
   BEGIN
     WAITFOR DELAY 00:01:00 --Set to whatever time increment you want to wait
     SELECT @CountProcessed = SUM(ControlField)
     FROM ControlTable
   END
```

You can then discard your SSIS variables, and simply start with this proc.  No constraints needed.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you very much for the reply. This looks like a good solution. Is there any way that we can achieve this inside SSIS package with out using Procedure.

Comment: @VenkatN You certainly can (although I still highly recommend against it for the visibility reasons I mentioned).  Your next best choice is to put the above into an execute script task, instead of building a procedure and calling it.  It will function the same way, but the code will live inside that task instead of in your database.

Answer (score 2):

## Script Task workaround

You can do a workaround using a `Script Task` instead of `Execute SQL Task`:

1. Inside the Script Task use a `SQLCommand` to retrieve the `RecordCount`
2. Add a While Loop that will repeat the `SqlCommand` execution until the `RecordCount = 8`
3. Your code should look like:

   ```
   Dim recordcount As Integer = 0
   Dim sqlQuery As String = ""
   Public Sub Main()

       sqlQuery = Dts.Variables.Item("User::SQLQueryForRecordCount ").Value.ToString

       Using sqlcon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;")

           sqlcon.Open()



           While recordcount < 8

               Using sqlcmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlcon)


                   recordcount = CInt(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar())
                   'Theading.Thread.Sleep(5000) wait for 5 seconds

               End Using



           End While


       End Using

       Dts.Variables.Item("User::RecordCount").Value = recordcount

       Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
   End Sub
   ```
4. At the end assign the Count Value to the `recordCount` Variable

*Note: that you must add `User::RecordCount` as ReadWriteVariable and `User::SQLQueryForRecordCount` as ReadOnly Variable in the Script editor*

*Side Note: you can add a `Theading.Thread.Sleep(5000)` command inside the `While loop` to give more time for each command execution*

Comment: Hi Hadi, Thank you very much for the reply. How can I state 'Windows Authentication' instead of password in SqlConnection. Sorry if I am asking basic questions. This is my first VB script in my career.

Comment: I have created VB script and following image has the details: [Script](https://prnt.sc/fc5a6m). I am getting following error when I run package [Error](https://prnt.sc/fc5apb). Please help me.

Comment: @VenkatN in the connection string you provided a server name without instance it should look like `myServerName\myInstanceName`

Comment: Our server doesn't have instance name. What should we provide if instance name is blank.

Comment: Server name is the machine name, instance is the sql server instance. You can get it from the oledb connection used in the execute sql task

Comment: I have added instance name to the script. this is the updated [Script](https://prnt.sc/fc62d6). Still it is giving same [Error](https://prnt.sc/fc62qm).

Comment: The code is fine. But the exception is unclear. Try adding a breakpoint on the first line of code and debug the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997381/runtime-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-from-sc